# What does "Vorstellung" and "Redemittel" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I came across this table in my textbook Studio D A1 and I don't know what those 2 words mean.

"Redemittel" is the vertical word in purple box. Redemittelkasten means "speech box" (thanks to Google Translate), so I guess Redemittel is speech?

**Context:**
[image]

Comment: What does your dictionary say? What could it be, according to the example already given?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich habe nirgends eine Übersetzung ins Englische gefunden. Und wenn ich die Bedeutung von "Redemittel" in solch einem Buch erklären müsste, müsste ich auch 'ne Weile nachdenken...

Comment: @IQV Zum Finden muss man suchen. Sofort beim ersten Mal gefunden: https://de.langenscheidt.com/deutsch-englisch/vorstellung#sense-1.1.1, https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Vorstellung, https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Redemittel.html, https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/Redemittel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Redemittel* are useful phrases in conversation.
They are like templates or building blocks (bigger than single words) that you can use.

*Vorstellung* in this case means introducing somebody, as in »Hi, my name is Morta.«